# Unable to parse json array using jackson json streaming

Tags: android, json, jackson, arrays

I am unable to parse below JSON stream that contains an array of object, here I have added just one object for simplification.

```
{
"status": true,
"categories": [
    {
        "obj_cat_id": "26",
        "session_user": "212233379",
        "timestamp": "2011-10-30 04:34:53"
    }
]
```

}

What I tried :

```
try {
        JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
        JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(is);
        jp.nextToken(); /* START_OBJECT */

        while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {

            if ("status".equals(jp.getCurrentName())) {
                jp.nextToken(); /* VALUE_TRUE */
                status = jp.getText();
                Constants.showLog("Status", jp.getText());
            } else if ("categories".equals(jp.getCurrentName())) {

                //jp.nextToken();
                while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                    //jp.nextToken();

                    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {

                        String namefieldOne = jp.getText();
                        Constants.showLog(TAG, namefieldOne);
                    }

                }

            } 
        }
        jp.close();
```

The major issue is that when I do jp.nextToken where the current token is START_ARRAY it goes directly to END_ARRAY and I am not able to access its object values.

I am using Jackson Streaming parser for better efficiency.

Comment: what error did you got?

Comment: no error,not getting categories array value?

Comment: you didn't get anything in here? Constants.showLog(TAG, namefieldOne); is there any exception catched by the try catch? please show your logcat

Comment: @NileshVerma : why u comment `jp.nextToken();` line inside `if ("categories".equals(jp.getCurrentName()))` ?

Comment: @NAYOSO there is no exception

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK if i put jp.nextToken(); this goes to end array

Comment: @NileshVerma : have u done or still facing same issue?

Comment: @NileshVerma : ok then use [this](http://pastebin.com/gnHXRA7U) code for parsing json string using jackson

Comment: thanx to all, issue in my webservices

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)? You can use it server-side or client-side (Android).
Saving shared preferences as JSON and stuff :)

```
public class Category {
       Long obj_cat_id;
       Long session_user;
       Timestamp timestamp;

       /* Getters && Setters */
}

public class MyEntity
{
        private boolean status;
        private List<Category> categories;

        /* Getters && Setters */
}

public class Serializer
{ 
    private static Gson _gson;

    static
    {
        _gson = new Gson();
    }

    public static <T> T jsonToObject(String json, Type type)
    {
        return _gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }

    public static <T> String getJson(T object)
    {
        Type type = new TypeToken<T>()
        {}.getType();
        return _gson.toJson(object, type);
    }
}
```

Using like this:

```
String myJsonString = "{
"status": true,
"categories": [
    {
        "obj_cat_id": "26",
        "session_user": "212233379",
        "timestamp": "2011-10-30 04:34:53"
    }
]
}";

MyEntity myEntity= Serializer.jsonToObject(myJsonString , MyEntity.class);
/* And vice-versa */
```

Comment: thnx, but im not using GSON,i m using Jackson (http://jackson.codehaus.org/) I required streaming parser.